# Max-Min Weighted Matching

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs, matching, bipartite-matching

The maximum weighted matching problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_weight_matching) finds a matching in a weighted graph that has maximum sum of weights. I was wondering if there are any existing approaches to find a matching that maximizes the minimum weight? (Can't seem to find any similar references on this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is known as the "bottleneck matching" problem.  Here is an algorithm for that problem.

There is a straightforward algorithm.  Pick a threshold $t$.  Delete all edges with weight below $t$ and check whether there is a matching in that graph.  Now do binary search on $t$, to find the largest $t$ such that the resulting graph has a matching.  This requires $O(\lg n)$ executions of a graph matching algorithm, and thus can be done in polynomial time.

I think there may be dedicated algorithms in the literature that may be even faster, but I'm not knowledgeable abou that.